# Meteor iterate list in template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have this:

```
Template.laps_t.laps = function () {
  return Practices.findOne({name: Session.get('practice')});
};
```

What do I have to do to iterate over this and put the values in paragraphs? I mean:

```
{{#each laps.lapList}}
  <p>WHAT DO I HAVE TO PUT HERE TO PRINT THE VALUES OF THE LIST????</p>
{{/each}}
```

Am I doing this right? What do I have to put inside that paragraph?

**EDIT:**

Thanks [Justin Case](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964023/justin-case), your solution did the trick.

Now I have one more problem. I want to print no only `lap.lapList` but also `lap.lapTimeList` (which is another list like `[1,2,3,4,5,...]`) in a table like so:

```
{{#each laps.lapList}}
  <tr>
    <td>iterate over and print the current value of lapList (solved using {{this}})</td>
    <td>iterate over and print the current value of lapTimeList</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

`laps` is the object that holds both `lapList` and `lapTimeList`. So, the idea is to print the lap number and the respective time. Does anyone knows how?

Comment: What do the elements of lapList look like?  You might want to look at the Meteor leaderboard example and pattern after it's "players" list.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If `laps.lapList` is an array in the form of `[1,2,3]` then:

```
{{#each laps.lapList}}
  <p>{{.}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

`{{.}}` refers to the current object/element. If it contains a dictionaries/hashes e.g. `[{elapsedTime:32.0, location: 'Chicago'}]` then you can use the key name:

```
{{#each laps.lapList}}
  <p>Lap took {{elapsedTime}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: You can also use `{{this}}` (in fact, I wasn't aware that `{{.}}` worked until now!)

Comment: Also, where do I find docs about this kind of template variables?

Comment: This is AWESOME! I've been stuck for ages on this matter, how come this piece of important knowledge is not easier to find on the interwebz?

Comment: @Mercutionario maybe people after spending too long digging for documentation, people feel they don't have time to note the answer on stackoverflow for something that should be so easy like looping over a list. Even though in reality if someone did that after spending an unusual amount of time digging, that it might save them later as well as thousands or millions of others? Anyone have any ideas on solutions on encouraging this sorta thing?

Comment: @LukeStanley Good point, and to promote this, posting on stackoverflow is okay, but what I think makes the difference is good and competent blogging by the influencers in each language/framework field, with users tipping the writers on what to write (this is key), or even guest-blogging on the influencers' popular online properties. This will ensure the information will be passed around more than on stackoverflow, and well-indexed by Google.